# "Error: no valid set of coefficients has been found: please supply starting values" when trying to get confidence intervals in R

Tags: r, confidence-interval, poisson-regression

I'm trying to analyze some count data for a few species ('Tetab' indicates the species in the below code). Consulting with a friend who is much more stats literate than I, he suggested analyzing the data with a Poisson regression, and then utilizing confidence intervals to determine which treatments resulted in significantly different count responses. This worked fine for the other two species I analyzed, but I'm getting the error listed in the title. Comparing the code, everything's the same among the different species' analyses, so I'm assuming it has something to do with the data - also because this species is the only one where the zero-inflated poisson regression can't be run. The total count data for the other two species is 33 and 47, but only 22 for Tetab. Could this be related to the error? Is there any workaround for this? The data is heterogenous for variances, so I can't utilize Kruskal-Wallis or multiple comparisons.

```
> Tetab.pglm <- glm(Count ~ Treatment, data = spond.spp.list[['Tetab']], family = poisson)
> Tetab.zpglm <- zeroinfl(Count ~ Treatment, data = spond.spp.list[['Tetab']], dist = "poisson")
Error in solve.default(as.matrix(fit$hessian)) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 1.63511e-19

> summary(Tetab.pglm)

Call:
glm(formula = Count ~ Treatment, family = poisson, data = spond.spp.list[["Tetab"]])

Deviance Residuals: 
 Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-1.35873  -0.00006  -0.00006   0.07899   2.36154  

Coefficients:
          Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept) -2.030e+01  4.311e+03  -0.005    0.996
Treatment2   2.004e+01  4.311e+03   0.005    0.996
Treatment3   9.922e-09  6.096e+03   0.000    1.000
Treatment4   2.022e+01  4.311e+03   0.005    0.996

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

Null deviance: 54.484  on 51  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 23.804  on 48  degrees of freedom
AIC: 68.297

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 18

> exp(coef(Tetab.zpglm))
Error in coef(Tetab.zpglm) : object 'Tetab.zpglm' not found
> exp(coef(Tetab.pglm))
 (Intercept)   Treatment2   Treatment3   Treatment4 
1.522998e-09 5.050767e+08 1.000000e+00 6.060920e+08 
> exp(confint(Tetab.zpglm))
Error in confint(Tetab.zpglm) : object 'Tetab.zpglm' not found
> exp(confint(Tetab.pglm))
Waiting for profiling to be done...
Error: no valid set of coefficients has been found: please supply starting values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: glm.fit: fitted rates numerically 0 occurred 
2: glm.fit: fitted rates numerically 0 occurred 
3: glm.fit: fitted rates numerically 0 occurred 
4: glm.fit: fitted rates numerically 0 occurred 
5: glm.fit: fitted rates numerically 0 occurred 
6: glm.fit: fitted rates numerically 0 occurred 
7: glm.fit: fitted rates numerically 0 occurred 
8: glm.fit: fitted rates numerically 0 occurred 
9: glm.fit: fitted rates numerically 0 occurred
```

Thanks for any help you can provide!
Max

Here's the data set:

```
Species Date    Site    Treatment   Count
Tetab   20160602    2   1   0
Tetab   20160602    2   2   1
Tetab   20160602    2   3   0
Tetab   20160602    2   4   1
Tetab   20160606    1   1   0
Tetab   20160606    1   2   1
Tetab   20160606    1   3   0
Tetab   20160606    1   4   0
Tetab   20160606    2   1   0
Tetab   20160606    2   2   1
Tetab   20160606    2   3   0
Tetab   20160606    2   4   0
Tetab   20160607    2   1   0
Tetab   20160607    2   2   0
Tetab   20160607    2   3   0
Tetab   20160607    2   4   1
Tetab   20160609    1   1   0
Tetab   20160609    1   2   0
Tetab   20160609    1   3   0
Tetab   20160609    1   4   2
Tetab   20160609    2   1   0
Tetab   20160609    2   2   0
Tetab   20160609    2   3   0
Tetab   20160609    2   4   1
Tetab   20160610    1   1   0
Tetab   20160610    1   2   1
Tetab   20160610    1   3   0
Tetab   20160610    1   4   0
Tetab   20160610    2   1   0
Tetab   20160610    2   2   1
Tetab   20160610    2   3   0
Tetab   20160610    2   4   0
Tetab   20160620    1   1   0
Tetab   20160620    1   2   1
Tetab   20160620    1   3   0
Tetab   20160620    1   4   1
Tetab   20160620    2   1   0
Tetab   20160620    2   2   1
Tetab   20160620    2   3   0
Tetab   20160620    2   4   4
Tetab   20160622    1   1   0
Tetab   20160622    1   2   0
Tetab   20160622    1   3   0
Tetab   20160622    1   4   1
Tetab   20160622    2   1   0
Tetab   20160622    2   2   2
Tetab   20160622    2   3   0
Tetab   20160622    2   4   1
Tetab   20160624    2   1   0
Tetab   20160624    2   2   1
Tetab   20160624    2   3   0
Tetab   20160624    2   4   0
```

Answer (score 5):

I can't solve this problem (yet), but I can diagnose some of what's going wrong.

This is a summary of your data:

```
 with(dd,table(Treatment,Count))
         Count
Treatment  0  1  2  4
        1 13  0  0  0
        2  4  8  1  0
        3 13  0  0  0
        4  5  6  1  1
```

You can see that treatments 1 and 3 have *all* of the values equal to zero.  When we fit a Poisson GLM to this, we fit the parameters on the *log scale* - that is, the intercept is the log-density of the first treatment, and the other parameters are differences between the log-density of the other treatments and the first. If we look at the coefficient table:

```
printCoefmat(coef(summary(Tetab.pglm)))
               Estimate  Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept) -2.0303e+01  4.3105e+03 -0.0047   0.9962
Treatment2   2.0040e+01  4.3105e+03  0.0046   0.9963
Treatment3   9.9225e-09  6.0960e+03  0.0000   1.0000
Treatment4   2.0223e+01  4.3105e+03  0.0047   0.9963
```

We see that all the parameters are large (+20/-20) except for treatment 3 which is basically zero; the standard errors are huge; and the p-values are basically 1.  The phenomenon of ridiculous standard errors is called the *Hauck-Donner effect*, and it occurs in this kind of extreme situation.

The zero-inflation stuff seems totally unnecessary here and will make an already difficult situation a bit harder.

In this case the maximum-likelihood estimate of the log-density for treatments 1 and 3 is actually $-\infty$, which is going to make life harder. It is *in principle* possible to compute a finite upper confidence interval for treatment 1 and lower confidence intervals for the differences between treatment 1 and (2,4), but it's going to be numerically ugly.

Probably (?) the best solution is some kind of *bias-reduced* or *penalized* estimate, which pushes the solution away from $-\infty$.  I thought `arm::bayesglm()` would do this, but I still got in trouble:

```
b1 <- bayesglm(Count ~ Treatment, data= dd, family=poisson)
```

gives reasonable answers, but `confint(b1)` still fails ...

Comment: Yes, I noticed those ridiculously high P-values and suspected they may be related to the problem. I don't completely understand your above response - sorry, I'm a bit statistically illiterate unfortunately - do you think perhaps a different statistical approach is warranted? Again, thank you for your help with this!

Comment: Given the small number of values >1, something I have done in the past (see Pasch et al. American Naturalist) is to collapse the data to binary (0/greater than 0) and use available tools for bias-reduced logistic regression (e.g. logistf, brglm packages)

Comment: Okay, thank you very much, Ben! I'll discuss this option with my more stats literate friend and collaborator. I really appreciate the time you've put into helping solve this issue! Cheers, Max